# how to use hooks inside task manager function used by background fetch on expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

it's possible to use hooks inside task manager function triggered with background fetch of expo react native?

or another ways to update the app state inside background fetch

I'm getting this error "TaskManager: Task "background-fetch" failed:, [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

here is my code on App.js

```
const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = 'background-fetch';

TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, async () => {
  const [sync, setSync] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(sync);

  const now = Date.now();
  console.log(`Got background fetch call at date: ${new Date(now).toISOString()}`);
   
  return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData;
});

function registerBackgroundFetchAsync() {
    console.log('register');
    return BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
      minimumInterval: 1,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      startOnBoot: true,
    });
}
```

and inside my component I'm registering the task after the load of some resources

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
            try {
                await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

                // Load our initial navigation state
                setInitialNavigationState(await getInitialState());

                // Load fonts
                await fetchFonts()
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e);
            } finally {
                setLoadingComplete(true);
                registerBackgroundFetchAsync();
                await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
            }
        }

        loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
    }, []);
```